# div element in table cell has some kind of spacing

Tags: css, html, css-tables

Ok, I know that using tables for layout is bad. But we have a client that has ie6 installed on all workstations and we have to make a complicated layout that works perfectly on it so the clean CSS solution didn't work so I had to do it with tables.

Here's the HTML code that I have :

```
<body>
<table id="main_table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="content">Content</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS that I have :

```
body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
     }
#main_table {
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border-spacing:0;
        width:100%;
     }
#main_table td {
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
     }
#main_table div.content {
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
     }
```

And for some mysterious reason, there's some kind of margin between the cell's top and the div. I'm absolutely positive that all my margins and paddings are at 0 but it's still there.

I tried :

- a span instead of the div and the problem is still there
- use `position:relative` on the table cell and position:absolute on the div but the div always take his position from the top left of the browser, not the top left of the element

Anyone had a similar problem in the past? Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: The problem is not only in IE6 but in all browsers.

Comment: try using firebug to see where is the margin

Comment: I tried to check with firebug and I don't see any margin or padding...

Comment: Ok now I feel like a complete Noob. I found the problem : It was that my cell add some height to it and the vertical-align was to the default value of middle. So the whole div was in the middle of the cell, and left what looked like a margin on top. I really feel idiot on this one... Thanks for everyone's input! I'll go find a cave and hide there for a few years... ;)

Comment: @Gabriel: If this was the solution, please post it as an Answer and mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that I completely forgot about picking up an answer for this question and it seems that 2 years later some people still feel the need to add new answers so here was the solution to my problem (that I posted in comments of my original question)

The problem was that my cell had some height to it and the vertical-align was to the default value of middle. So the whole div was in the middle of the cell, and left what looked like a margin on top.

So it was not a real problem, just me no longer being used to do html layout with tables...

There, that is the answer to the problem... Now if someone can close this question to prevent any further comments/answers, it would be great... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `#main_table tr td` or possibly `#main_table tbody tr td` to get at the cells and remove their padding and margin, but I'm not 100% sure.  Does it display properly in other browsers right now?  Can you verify that your css rules are being applied to your cells with something like the IE Developer Toolbar?

Comment: I should have specified that the problem is not only present in IE6 but in other browsers also... I'll update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

ie6 = the enemy of the world. no guarantee but try things like putting "0px" instead of just "0".

Also have you tried putting `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">`?

Can't really think of much else.

Can we have a link to play about with?

Answer (score 0):

Having you tried cellpadding/spacing. I can't test it as I don't have IE6. I don't even support IE6 anymore, Microsoft has dropped support for it and if they no longer support it I'm  not going to either.

```
<table id="main_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: It seems that Microsoft continued to support IE6 for large organisations. Since this problem if for the intranet of a large organisation like that, it's difficult not to support it. The rest of the time, I do not support IE6 anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
body { line-height:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

My general-purpose fix for IE-6 padding/margin issues was (because we don't support it anymore) to give the offending container element the IE-proprietary [zoom property](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1354-The-Power-Of-ZOOM-Fixing-CSS-Issues-In-Internet-Explorer.htm) with a value of 100% to trigger hasLayout. YMMV.

```
#main_table td div.content { zoom:100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `'reset.css'` in your project? Because most of the time if we do not specify any styles for any element, them browser uses its default settings on those places.

Answer (score 0):

@Gabriel  You might be knowing that, all browsers have some default settings and and when we don't give any style to any tag, then the browser  gives its default styles to that specific tag. I would suggest you to use 'reset.css' which you can find [here](http://www.cssreset.com/) in your project. there four types of css given, out of which Eric Meyer’s “Reset CSS” is best.